# can I pull information after a keyword

Tags: xpath, scrapy

i am running a spider that is pulling information like prices and shipping ... I am getting the shipping information back like this "Shipping:$.99,Shipping:,Shipping:,Shipping:$.49" .... the code that is extracting it looks like this

```
item["shipping"] = vendor.xpath("normalize-space(.//span[@class='shippingAmount']/text())").extract()
```

can i write this line to pull just the price after the "Shipping:" ?

Comment: Which result do you want: "$.99", both "$.99" and "$.49", or "$1.48"?

Comment: I am trying to get this :  [$.99,,,$.99]

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of `substring-after` and `substring-before`, ie.

```
substring-before(
  substring-after(
    "Shipping:$.99,Shipping:,Shipping:,Shipping:$.49",
    "Shipping:"),
  ","
)
```

In XPath 1.0, there is no way to fetch all shipping amounts for an arbitrary number of shipping fees. You could query the 2nd, 3td, ... value by repeatedly calling `substring-after($string, "Shipping:")` to remove the former value.

*(Linebreaks can be omitted, of course.)*

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the prices using some regular expression :

```
import re 
str = "Shipping:$.99,Shipping:,Shipping:,Shipping:$.49"
re.findall(r'[\d+[.]]?\d+', str)
['.99', '.49']
```

### EDIT

To have 0 if there is no shipping:

```
[float(x) if x else 0 for x in re.sub('Shipping:[$]?','',str).split(',')]
[0.99, 0, 0, 0.49]
```

Comment: You can even do that with scrapy selectors that support a `re()` method: `item["shipping"] = vendor.xpath("normalize-space(.//span[@class='shippingAmount']/text())").re(r'([\d+[.]]?\d+)')`

Comment: This code works, but i need a small adjustment.  I am running this line: item["shipping"] = vendor.xpath("normalize-space(.//span[@class='shippingAmount']/text())").re(r"([\d+[.]]?\d+)") ... this returns something like: 'shipping': [u'.99', u'.01', u'.24'], ... is there a way to have it show 0 when there is no shipping?  There should be two 0 fields in the array